# String Equation parser issue

Tags: android, string, math

I'm coding a method that solve various kind of equation. Now I want that the method receives a String equation that could be in the forms:

```
ax^2+bx+c=0
```

or

```
*ax^2+c=0*
```

or

```
bx+c=0
```

etc. and the order shouldn't matter.

My problem is: **How could I parse the equation according the "x" grade?**

The eq could contains more values of the same grade for example 2x^2+4x^2+3x+8=2 (max grade x^3).

My method should assign the a value to `double a[]` if on the left or on the right of a there is `x^2`, `double b[]`, if on the left or on the right there is `x`, and `double c[]` if there isn't any `x` variable near the value (and should change the value sign if the therms is after the ***=***).

Convert a String number in a double is simple but I don't know how I could disassemble the input String according the `x` grade as described.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a quadratic equation?

Comment: only quadratic and no cubic or higher?

Comment: Wny dont you just solve for x using the standard formula? http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/quadraticeq/quadraformula/quadraformula.html

Comment: @smk
because I want to implement a method that automatically recognize the input String also if is in the canonical form ax^2+bx+c=0, and extend the method to cubic equation etc.

Comment: The symbol for power would be ^ right?

Comment: @HoanNguyen Yes, would be the ^

Comment: Right side always 0? or it could be ax = c for example?

Comment: @HoanNguyen no, if isn't 0 the method should divide all the others x terms by this and sum to c the value

Comment: I just one to make sure that the string is always end with = 0. Is it right? If it is then it is pretty easy.

Comment: The right side is all 0 in your post. Or is it the string can be in any form that if rearrange would be a polynomial equation?

Comment: @HoanNguyen the important is that the method assign the values according the grade and not according the offset, because the eq could contains more values of the same grade for example 2x^2+4x^6+3x+8=2.

Comment: You mean 4x^2 and not 4x^6 right? Otherwise it would be a 6 degree polynomial equation.

Comment: It is not hard, I just want to know exactly the string could contain before I write up the answer.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Yes 4x^2... however the max grade should be x^3 for the moment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't limited by Android, I'd suggest using a lexer and parser. These are code generators, so they can work anywhere the base language works, but they tend to produce bloated code.  Android might not appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Tested for `-2x + 3x^2   - 2 + 3x = 3 - 2x^2`

```
public Double[] parseEquation(String equation)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "equation: " + equation);
    // Remove all white spaces
    equation = equation.replaceAll("[ ]", "");


    // Get the left and right sides of =    
    String[] sides = equation.split("[=]");  // should be of size 2
    boolean leftNegative = false;
    boolean rightNegative = false;
    if (sides.length != 2)
    {
        // There is no = or more than one = signs.
    }
    else
    {
        // if sides i starts with + remove the + 
        // if - we remove and put it back later
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (sides[i].charAt(0) == '+')
            {
                sides[i] = sides[i].substring(1);
            }
        }

        if (sides[0].charAt(0) == '-')
        {
            leftNegative = true;
            sides[0] = sides[0].substring(1);
        }
        if (sides[1].charAt(0) == '-')
        {
            rightNegative = true;
            sides[1] = sides[1].substring(1);
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "left side:" + sides[0] + " right side: " + sides[1]);

    // Terms without signs need to find out later
    String[] leftTerms = sides[0].split("[+-]");
    String[] rightTerms = sides[1].split("[+-]");

    int length = leftTerms[0].length();
    if (leftNegative)
    {
        leftTerms[0] = "-" + leftTerms[0];
    }
    // put in the minus sign for the rest of the terms

    for (int i = 1; i < leftTerms.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "length = " + length + " " + sides[0].charAt(length));
        if (sides[0].charAt(length) == '-')
        {
            leftTerms[i] = "-" + leftTerms[i];
            length += leftTerms[i].length();
        }
        else
        {
            length += leftTerms[i].length() + 1;
        }   
    }

    length = rightTerms[0].length();
    if (rightNegative)
    {
        rightTerms[0] = "-" + rightTerms[0];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rightTerms.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "length = " + length + " " + sides[1].charAt(length));
        if (sides[1].charAt(length) == '-')
        {
            rightTerms[i] = "-" + rightTerms[i];
            length += rightTerms[i].length();
        }
        else
        {
            length += rightTerms[i].length() + 1;
        }   
    }
    //  Now we put all the factors and powers in a list
    List<ContentValues> leftLists = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

    // left side
    for (int i = 0; i < leftTerms.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "leftTerm: " + leftTerms[i]);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        int indexOfX = leftTerms[i].indexOf('x');
        if (indexOfX == -1)
        {
            // no x mean a constant term
            contentValues.put("factor", leftTerms[i]);
            contentValues.put("power", "0");
        }
        else
        {
            int indexOfHat = leftTerms[i].indexOf('^');
            if (indexOfHat == -1)
            {
                // no hat mean power = 1
                contentValues.put("power", "1");
                String factor = leftTerms[i].substring(0, indexOfX).trim();
                contentValues.put("factor", factor);
            }
            else
            {
                String power = leftTerms[i].substring(indexOfX + 2).trim();
                String factor = leftTerms[i].substring(0, indexOfX).trim();
                contentValues.put("factor", factor);
                contentValues.put("power", power);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, contentValues.toString());
        leftLists.add(contentValues);
    }

    List<ContentValues> rightLists = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rightTerms.length; i++)
    {           
        Log.d(TAG, "rightTerm: " + rightTerms[i]);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        int indexOfX = rightTerms[i].indexOf('x');
        if (indexOfX == -1)
        {
            // no hat mean a constant term
            contentValues.put("factor", rightTerms[i]);
            contentValues.put("power", "0");
        }
        else
        {
            int indexOfHat = rightTerms[i].indexOf('^');
            if (indexOfHat == -1)
            {
                // no hat mean power = 1
                contentValues.put("power", "1");
                String factor = rightTerms[i].substring(0, indexOfX).trim();
                contentValues.put("factor", factor);
            }
            else
            {
                String power = rightTerms[i].substring(indexOfX + 2).trim();
                String factor = rightTerms[i].substring(0, indexOfX).trim();
                contentValues.put("factor", factor);
                contentValues.put("power", power);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, contentValues.toString());
        rightLists.add(contentValues);
    }
    // Now add the factors with same powers.
    // Suppose we solve for cubic here the end result will be 
    // 4 terms constant, x, x^2 and x^3
    // Declare a double array of dim 4 the first will hold constant
    // the second the x factor etc...
    // You can allow arbitrary power by looping through the lists and get the max power
    Double[] result = new Double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    for (ContentValues c : leftLists)
    {
        switch (c.getAsInteger("power"))
        {
            case 0:
                //Log.d(TAG, "power = 0, factor = " + c.toString());
                result[0] += c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;

            case 1:
                result[1] += c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
            case 2:
                result[2] += c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
            case 3:
                result[3] += c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
        }
    }

    for (ContentValues c : rightLists)
    {
        switch (c.getAsInteger("power"))
        {
            case 0:
                //Log.d(TAG, "power = 0, factor = " + c.toString());
                result[0] -= c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;

            case 1:
                result[1] -= c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
            case 2:
                result[2] -= c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
            case 3:
                result[3] -= c.getAsDouble("factor");
                break;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "constant term = " + result[0] + ", x^1 = " + result[1]
                 + ", x^2 = " + result[2] + ", x^3 = " + result[3]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there are some syntax errors, I have tried to fix something but the app crashes. could you improve the posted code?